# Remove line breaks in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, text

I haven't found a solution yet in StackOverlfow to my problem.

I'm using `nl2br()` in PHP to insert linebreaks `<br>` instead of \n when storing a message on the database. The thing is I want to have a preview of that message that has no linebreaks. HOw do I remove the linebreaks `<br>` ?

I have tried `text.replace('<br>', '');`

```
"Hi guys!"
<br>
<br>
"How are you?"
```

Should be

```
"Hi guys! guys how are you?"
```

Comment: Not directly linked to your problem, but really, it is: You should store your data raw. So store the \n in your database and do all the cleaning up on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the exact code that you've tried and doesn't work?? This works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "Hi guys!<br><br>How are you?";
    str = str.replace(/<br>/g, " ");
    alert(str); // Gives "Hi guys!  How are you?" (Double spaced, due to 2 <br>'s being replaced)
    str = str.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
    alert(str); // Correct! "Hi guys! How are you?"
</script>
```

`text.replace('<br>', '');` isn't a global replacement.

Comment: Both doesn't work either but I'm using `lastMessage.innerHTML = data[i].lastMessage.replace(/<br>/g, " ");` ?

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what actually happens with that code, does it error? Does it not display anything? If so I'd try debugging with a basic `alert(data[i].lastMessage);`, and see if you're actually getting the correct data back.

Comment: The `/\s\s+/g` is a regular expression. It basically means '[space[space]REPEAT', so it will replace 2+ spaces. The `g` at the end means global, so it will replace all instances. The `/` characters are the regex delimiters.

Comment: Alert with the code mentioned abve gives you `Hi guys!<br />
<br />
How are you= I was wondering if you could send me the draft?`

Comment: There's your problem, you told us you needed to replace `<br>`, but you instead need to replace `<br />`. Try `lastMessage.innerHTML = data[i].lastMessage.replace(/<br \/>/g, "");`. Note that I also removed the space from the quotes, as you already have spaces in there. You will still require the second replacement though, as there's 2 spaces. This is the final: `lastMessage.innerHTML = data[i].lastMessage.replace(/<br \/>/g, "").replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function ripBr(str,replacement){
        return str.replace(/<br*>/gi,replacement);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: This will match `<b>`, `<br>`, `<brr>`, ..., but not `<br />`, `<br clear="all">` or any number of other variations.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/<br[^>]*>/gi, '')
```